# Sending e-mails through specified account

Tags: excel, vba, email, outlook

When I send an assignment to students, I create an individualized file I want each student to work on. I generate the files using VBA and Excel.

I put Outlook in "Work Offline" mode so I can make sure the e-mails have the correct attachments before I put Outlook back online. I usually then hit the "send/receive all folders" button so they'll go out immediately while I'm watching.
This works at work where I have Outlook configured with just my work e-mail.

On Outlook at home (the installed app on a Windows 10 machine), I have two accounts configured.
Account #1 is a personal e-mail from a personal domain.
Account #2 is my e-mail account for work.

I want to generate e-mails like I do at work, and for them to go in the outbucket of my work account. I would then send them from there.

However, they go into the outbucket of my personal account. I don't want students to get an e-mail from an unrecognized sender. Nor do I want them replying to those e-mails.

The code to create e-mails:

```vb
Sub makemail()
    Dim strLocation As String
    Dim OutApp As Object
    Dim OutMail As Object
    Dim OutAccount As Object
 
    Range("a1").Activate
    
    eaddy = ActiveCell.Offset(0, 4).Value 'student's e-mail address in a worksheet
    IndivFile = ActiveCell.Offset(0, 8).Value 'this is an identifier for the student's individual file
    LastName = ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Value ' student's last name
    
    Do Until ActiveCell.Value = ""
        Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
        
        Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)
        Set OutAccount = OutApp.Session.Accounts.Item(1)
        
        On Error Resume Next
        With OutMail
            .To = eaddy
            .CC = ""
            .BCC = ""
            .Subject = LastName & " (text that describes the assignment)"
            .Body = "(body of message)"
            strLocation = "(location of the individual attachments" & IndivFile & ".xlsx"
            .Attachments.Add (strLocation)
            .Send
        End With
        On Error GoTo 0
    
        Set OutMail = Nothing
        Set OutApp = Nothing
        Set OutAccount = Nothing
    
        With Application
            .ScreenUpdating = True
            .EnableEvents = True
        End With
        
        ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Activate
        eaddy = ActiveCell.Offset(0, 4).Value
        IndivFile = ActiveCell.Offset(0, 8).Value
        LastName = ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Value
    Loop

End Sub
```

It dumps the generated e-mails into the outbucket of account #1: my personal account.

I tried replacing `.Send` with `.SendUsingAccount = OutApp.Session.Accounts.Item(2)`

Putting anything in the parentheses (including a 0 or 1) will mean I don't see the output in either outbucket. (No idea if the e-mails even generated. they're probably sitting in some directory I haven't looked in.)

So, I just generated all the e-mails and they showed up in my personal account's outbucket.
I selected them all and dropped them into the outbucket of my work account.
I clicked the "send/receive" and they won't go anywhere.

If I open each e-mail individually and click the "send" button in the e-mail, they go. I see them in my sent folder.

I don't know that much about Outlook. I wonder if this is some sort of mismatched certificate problem on the e-mails? But if that were the case, why don't they go in bulk, but will go if sent individually with the e-mail open?

I just tested. if the e-mails are marked read or unread, it makes no difference.

I did set my work-email as the primary in Outlook (File > Account Settings > Designate one account as the primary one.

My questions:

1. Is there a way, code-wise, to put this in the second account's outbucket (work)?
   Keep in mind that `.SendUsingAccount = OutApp.Session.Accounts.Item(2)` did not work.
2. If I can't do that, is there a way to change my e-mail accounts so the work one is #1?
   Other than deleting and re-installing in a specific order?
   I did go in and make the work-email my primary e-mail.
3. Why won't they send in one outbucket (because they were dragged and dropped from another outbucket), but will send if you open them individually?

Comment: `.SentOnBehalfOfName = "workemail@work.com"`? Note the emails will still appear in the sent box of your core account but the from addres will appear as the email you enter for this operator. Replies will go back to that account as well

Comment: Oh.  Okay, that's a clear improvement. I'd seen that method before, but didn't understand it. Thanks!

Comment: That’s what I use so it shouldn’t be a problem unless you absolutely need the items to show up in the work outbox. If you are sending sensitive info that could be a problem you’d want to consider

Comment: The only thing I could see as a problem is that first e-mail box is on a very inexpensive personal web hosting platform. I'll have to see if there's a limit on how much I use that e-mail box.  I send a TON of e-mails every year, with attachments.

Comment: Okay, that didn't really work. I think it may work if both accounts are on the same server. For instance, 2 people working for the same employer?

Just tried this and it didn't work. E-mail never went thru.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you just need to set/change the default account in Outlook.

[image]

See [How To Set An Email Account As The Default Account In Outlook?](https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/outlook/1677-outlook-set-default-account.html) for more information.

Also, you can use the [SendUsingAccount](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.mailitem.sendusingaccount) property of Outlook items which sets an `Account` object that represents the account under which the MailItem is to be sent. The `SendUsingAccount` property can be used to specify the account that should be used to send the `MailItem` when the `Send` method is called.

```
         Sub SendEmailFromAccount(ByVal application As Outlook.Application, _ 
            ByVal subject As String, ByVal body As String, ByVal recipients As String, ByVal smtpAddress As String) 

            ' Create a new MailItem and set the To, Subject and Body properties. 
            Dim newMail As Outlook.MailItem = DirectCast(application.CreateItem(Outlook.OlItemType.olMailItem), Outlook.MailItem) 
            newMail.To = recipients 
            newMail.Subject = subject 
            newMail.Body = body 

            ' Retrieve the account that has the specific SMTP address. 
            Dim account As Outlook.Account = GetAccountForEmailAddress(application, smtpAddress) 
            ' Use this account to send the email. 
            newMail.SendUsingAccount = account 
            newMail.Send() 
        End Sub 

        Function GetAccountForEmailAddress(ByVal application As Outlook.Application, ByVal smtpAddress As String) As Outlook.Account 

            ' Loop over the Accounts collection of the current Outlook session. 
            Dim accounts As Outlook.Accounts = application.Session.Accounts 
            Dim account As Outlook.Account 
            For Each account In accounts 
                ' When the email address matches, return the account. 
                If account.SmtpAddress = smtpAddress Then 
                    Return account 
                End If 
            Next             
        End Function
```

Comment: Yeah, I did that prior to running all the tests. That didn't work, either. The work account has been primary since yesterday. Ran tests today. the e-mails still dumped into the other account.

Comment: I needed 2 extra things to get this to work. First is to set the account to use, then to use "set" with the .sendusingaccount.

After that it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, found it out. Part of it depended on going to Tools > References and then making sure I've got Microsoft Outlook 16.0 Object Library is selected. Granted, you can do this without early bindings, but it seemed to help.

Here is the code I eventually came up with:

```
Sub makemail()
Range("a1").Activate
    eaddy = ActiveCell.Offset(0, 4).Value
    IndivFile = ActiveCell.Offset(0, 8).Value
    LastName = ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Value

    Dim objOutlook As Object
    Dim objMail As Object

    Worksheets("Rollcall").Activate
    Set objOutlook = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Dim oAccount As Outlook.Account
    Set oAccount = Outlook.Application.Session.Accounts(1)

    Debug.Print oAccount
    If oAccount = "outlook account you want to use" Then
        Debug.Print ("condition true")

           'Main Logic ============================================
           Do Until ActiveCell.Value = ""
               Set objMail = objOutlook.CreateItem(0)
               On Error Resume Next
               With objMail
                   .To = eaddy
                   '.CC = ""
                   '.BCC = ""
                   .Subject = (your subject)
                   .Body = "your outgoing message"
                   strLocation = "(location of attachment"
                   .Attachments.Add (strLocation)
                  Set .SendUsingAccount = oAccount
                   .Send
               End With

               Set objMail = Nothing

               ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Activate
               eaddy = ActiveCell.Offset(0, 4).Value
               IndivFile = ActiveCell.Offset(0, 8).Value
               LastName = ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Value
           Loop
        Set objOutlook = Nothing
    End If
End Sub
```